# Getting a possible leak using gulp watch, tasks take longer each time

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I'm using gulp to compile and minify my SASS in an ASP.NET5 website to use as a CDN. I've written a watcher that watches my *.scss files, it then uses dependencies to compile the scss and then concat/minify it into one style.min.css.

The issue I'm having is that the longer the project is open, or at least with each sequential run of the gulp tasks, they get considerably longer to the point where I had only been developing for about 20 minutes, and the compile task was taking 15+ second, and the minify was taking 25+ seconds. The very first run of each takes about 1 or 2 milliseconds so I'm really lost as to what's going on.

Here's my watcher:

```
gulp.task('Watch:Sass', function () {
    watch(paths.cdn.sassLoc, { verbose: true }, function () {
        gulp.start("Min:css"); 
    });
});
```

Here is the `Min:css` task:

```
gulp.task("Min:css", ["Compile:Sass"], function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.cdn.cssLoc, "!" + paths.cdnMinCssLoc + "**/*.*"])
        .pipe(concat(paths.cdn.cssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

And here is the `Compile:Sass` task that is being injected as a dependency:

```
gulp.task('Compile:Sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.cdn.imagesLoc)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/css/min/images'));
    return gulp.src(paths.cdn.sassLoc).pipe(plumber({
        handleError: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cdn.sassDest));
});
```

Could it be because of my use of returns?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have to restart Visual Studio every half hour or so which gets extremely frustrating!

I'm sure I've included everything relevant, but please ask if you require any more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it was in fact my return statements that were in the wrong place.

In order to fix the issue, I had to take off the return on the `gulp.src(...)` and I had to add a `return true` to the end of the `Compile:Sass` gulp task. I also took the return off of the `Min:Css` task completely and now my compile task takes ~1.5ms and my min task takes ~600us.

Here's the final `Compile:Sass` task:

```
gulp.task('Compile:Sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.cdn.imagesLoc)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/css/min/images'));
    gulp.src(paths.cdn.sassLoc).pipe(plumber({
        handleError: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cdn.sassDest));

    return true;
});
```

Comment: This is because `return true;` gets executed immediately after `gulp.src`. This happens, because gulp.src and the pipe calls are asynchronous. The file is effectively written to disk after your compile function returned control to gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Matt, you have a concat on one of your "Min:css" task pipes.

```
gulp.task("Min:css", ["Compile:Sass"], function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.cdn.cssLoc, "!" + paths.cdnMinCssLoc + "**/*.*"])
        .pipe(concat(paths.cdn.cssDest))
        ...
        ...
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

Make sure that you are not infinitely concatenating that same css over and over and over again. I can't tell what your `paths.cdn.cssLoc` points to. That would account for longer and longer processing time. You can call that a leak if you want.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply,I have no internet. paths.cdn.cssLoc is "./wwwroot/css/**/*.css". I am, however using `"!" + paths.cdnMinCssLoc + "**/*.*"` which I thought would exclude that path from the compiling.

Comment: You are excluding a path that does not exist. '"!" + paths.cdnMinCssLoc + "**/*.*"' expands to '!./wwwroot/css/**/*.css**/*.*', which is syntactically incorrect. As good practice, end your paths with '/'. Anyhow, check that.

Comment: I changed that guy that didn't fix it. The issue was indeed my return statements, I'll add an answer to the question.